# can not connect to SQL database on amazon EC2 - microsoft project server database

Tags: asp.net, amazon-ec2, connection-string

I am using SQL managment studio 2008 running on an Amazon EC2 machine. I am unable to connect to the database in my asp.net application. The EC2 instance has been set to accept connections over the SQL port. I am also able to remote the machine as well as view websites hosted on the server. Listed below is part of the connection string relating to this instance. When the program is ran and this connection string is called, it returns tcp error 0 - no return response. it just times out.

```
<add name="ProjectServer" connectionString="Data Source=*IP ADDRESS HERE*,1433;Initial Catalog=*Catalog Name*;User ID=IP-0A6ED514\Administrator;"/>
```

I removed the ip and the catalog name for the example, but I am sure they are correct.

The only thing that I could think may cause an error, is the differences in names between the user id and the server name - the server name is ip-0A6ED514\sharepoint but the user name is ip-0A6ED514\administrator when I log into the sql server manager on the EC2 instance. A password is not used. Not sure if I would need to leave in a blank string for password - also not sure if the difference between server name and user id to log in makes a difference. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

update - when this connection string is used with out the port, i get tcp provider error 40 - when the port is in there, i get error 0

edit-  the sql server is using windows authentication - does this make a difference? Usually I always use SQL server authentication

edit 2- now running sql express at same location, would i need a \SQLEXPRESS tag? I feel like after looking around and what could be the error, it is that I am reaching the machine ok, but its not pointing me to the DB, any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, use \SQLEXPRESS.  I have sql express running on some EC2 instances and I use localhost\SQLEXPRESS when connecting via SSMS.  Can you successfully connect to the sql instance using SSMS?

Comment: i can connect on the amazon instance to the database, but i can't use localhost because the application is running from my local machine, not from the amazon server.

Comment: After rereading your initial conn string, I think there are multiple issues here.  You can't use Windows authentication and specify a username and password.  And since I'm assuming your EC2 instance is not a member of a domain along with your remote computer, Windows auth isn't going to work well/easily.  Use SQL authentication to simplify this?

Comment: Looking into seeing if we can switch it over, I'm not the only one who uses the database. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I should mention that I believe it is possible to use Windows auth on a non-domain setup. On Windows 7, you have to go into Windows control panel > User Accounts > Manage your credentials, then add a username/password that Windows will use when it attempts to connect to the remote machine. I've had issues getting this to work in the past, but in theory this should work. Then you don't specify username/password in the conn string. I would go with sql auth in this case if possible though, less problematic down the road.

Comment: Mixed mode auth would give you both (if changing to sql auth would break other things).  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx

Comment: Were you able to resolve it? I've same problem right now. Please help me if you can.

Comment: try checking your security groups, make sure to have port 1433 open for connections (with ip as 0.0.0.0 to allow all). also make sure any other ports you need to allow connection from/to are listed in the rule for the security group you are using. i'm not sure if this solved the particular issue listed but this is frequently the case.

Comment: where do I check for the ports?

Comment: in your amazon aws web console. add a new security group in RDS - allow it to take permissions from your EC2 group, and in the EC2 group make sure 0.0.0.0/0:1433 is allowed